# CXF doesn't add "urn:" to XML tags

Tags: xml, soap, cxf

I'm using CXF to create a SOAP client and SoapUI to test it. I found that CXF isn't creating the XML tags correctly. The SOAP petition should look like:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:WS_Incid">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<urn:GetFirstDate>
<urn:id_enterprise>XXXX</urn:id_enterprise>
</urn:GetFirstDate>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But I checked with wireshark and I receive:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<GetFirstDate xmlns="urn:WS_Incid">
<id_enterprise>XXX</id_enterprise>
</GetFirstDate>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Since CXF doesn't send "urn:" in the XML tags, SoapUI seems to have trouble parsing it.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: The bug is with SoapUI rather than CXF - those two XMLs are equivalent as far as any proper namespace-aware XML tool is concerned.

Comment: I'm not sure, but there's another difference: in the first one, there is xmlns:urn="urn:WS_Incid", but in the second one, it is xmlns="urn:WS_Incid". Can this affect the result?

Comment: With namespaced XML, all that matters to the SOAP tool is the namespace URIs and the "local" element names.  In both cases, there is an element named `Body` in the `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` namespace, containing a child called `GetFirstDate` in the `urn:WS_Incid` namespace.  The first example achieves this by binding a prefix to the URI and then prefixing the `GetFirstDate` element name, the second does it by using a default namespace declaration on the `GetFirstDate` itself, but both are equivalent ways to represent the same data.

Comment: As @IanRoberts said both xmls are same. its the namespace which matters and not the prefix and where its placed. Check if your namespace is correct. If you need to customize prefix, you can add it in your package-info.class  elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, xmlns={@XmlNs(prefix="ns0", namespaceURI="{namespace}"}

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found how to fix it: I had to use "ns1" as namespace

```
def argid = holder.getNodeValue("//ns1:id_enterprise")
```